# Why do Russian speakers call Vladimir Putin "Vladimir Vladimirovich"?

Tags: выбор-имени, терминология

Everything is in the title, sorry if I misspelled it.

Why do Russian speakers call Vladimir Putin "Vladimir Vladimirovich" ?

Comment: Is Wikipedia allowed in the answers? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic#Russian

Comment: Not only Russians, during Putin's visit to North Korea anchors on DPRK's TV referred him using fully qualified name: "Vladimir Vladimirovich Putin". With Korean accent, of course.

Comment: Related http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/14025/what-is-the-difference-between

Comment: Also related: http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/11598/what-order-are-the-parts-of-a-full-russian-name-in

Comment: In Russia, when you speak face-to-face with someone older than you, or higher by status, or to emphasize respect - you name him by First - Patronymic. When you mention someone in absentia, this form is used to emphasize respect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A full Russian name consists of:

> - First name
> - Patronymic (derived from father's first name)
> - Last name, also known as family name.

Russian president's full name is: Vladimir (first name) Vladimirovich (patronymic) Putin (last name).

The following combinations of names are used in a formal environment:

> 1. *First Patronymic Last* - **Vladimir Vladimirovich Putin** - very formal
> 2. *First Patronymic* - **Vladimir Vladimirovich** - moderately formal
> 3. *First Last* - **Vladimir Putin** - moderately formal, the same level of formality as #2.

More information on the order of Russian names is available here: [What order are the parts of a full Russian name in?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/11598/what-order-are-the-parts-of-a-full-russian-name-in)

Comment: I disagree, #2 and #3 are not interchangeable. #2 is used to address the person, #3 is use way rarely for that purposes.

Comment: I agree that #3 is not a proper way to **address** someone formally.  But it's an acceptable form to refer to someone formally. For example: "...сообщил «Известиям» участник работы над докладом член-корреспондент РАН Иван Иванов..."  The answer does not state that all 3 forms can be used to address someone.

Comment: Journalists address to Putin: “Владимир Владимирович, бла-бла-бла ?” And, I think, it is the most popular way. 
Informal, you can address or refer to everyone whatever you like. If you create political meme about Вован or Donald, no-one will think about the pranker or the Duck.
How journalists address to Trump by name?

Comment: It is worth adding that the patronymic is not based on the first name (this might be a cause of confusion, as both have root *Vladimir*). @yalov *Vladimir Vladimirovich* roughly corresponds to *Mr. Putin* in in English usage, although in case of a president one would usually say *Mr. President*.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Russia, your second name is your father's full name+vich/ovich
For example, my name is Mikhail and my dad's name is vladimir (coincidentally). So, my full name is Mikhail Vladimirovich+family name. For females, the second name will have vna/ovna instead of vich/ovich. Hope this helps)

Comment: It's called "patronymic", not "second name". Come on, comments is full of it already.

Answer (score -1):

Russian names have a first name "imya" (Vladimir), second name "otchestvo" (Vladimirovich (the name of father)) and third name "familiya" (Putin).

Comment: It's called "patronymic", not "second name". Come on, comments is full of it already.